# GLFW fails to initialize on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, codeblocks, glfw

Here is the code which I'm trying to run:

```cpp
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    do{
        // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !


        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

It only shows a black window with the text:

```
Failed to initialize GLFW
```

Also, I've already linked `GL`, `GLEW`, `SDL2` and `glfw3` to the build options.

Comment: What does `glfwGetError()` and/or a `glfwSetErrorCallback()` output?

Comment: Also, are you trying to do anything weird like run this over remote X11 or inside a VM/WSL?

Comment: Does your GPU support OpenGL? Is it a weird GPU?